# Adding a line to an XML file after specific Tags

Tags: xml, unix-utils, append

How would you guys go about adding a line to a bunch of XML files after certain tags?
Solution can be based in usage of unix tools or name a text editor or utility that could allow me to do this quickly and easily. I have over 60 files that I need to edit.

For instance I have the following XML:

```
  <Node disablePersistence="true">
     <Name>Mapper</Name>
     <Action>
        <Class-Name>com.test.component.Mapper</Class-Name>
        <Param name="output_url" value="constant:file:///output.xml"/>
        <Param name="xml_url" value="constant:file:///input.xml"/>
        <Param name="xsl_url" value="constant:file:///template.xsl"/>
     </Action>
     <Next-Node>ComposeMessage</Next-Node>
  </Node>
```

First I would need to search for the tag Node.
Then I would need to search for the tag Name = Mapper.
Then search for the tag Action. Then search for the tag Param.
Where all tags for Param are then we need to insert the new line:

```
        <Param name="new_parameter" value="constant:true"/>
```

Is this possible or is it asking too much and it will be faster to manually edit all files?

Comment: definitely possible. use Notepad++ under windows or Sublime Text under  either unix or Windows and look at search replace option with regex (regular expression). You regular expression may be a bit complex but will resolve your problem for any amount of files

Comment: Perhaps this provides some ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772125/editing-xml-files It can certainly be done with unix scripting, but xml-specific tools will be more likely to deal with unexpected differences in input properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, a solution using `xmlstarlet` and XPath. I've extended the XML to demonstrate that we can pick out specific nodes:

Solution

```
xmlstarlet edit \
    --subnode '//Node[Name/text()="Mapper"]/Action' --type elem --name 'Param' \
    --var nap '$prev' \
    --insert '$nap' --type attr --name 'name' --value 'new_parameter' \
    --insert '$nap' --type attr --name 'constant:true'
```

We create a new subnode of `Node/Action` where there is also an element `Name` that has the text value `Mapper`. We assign this new node to the XPath variable `nap` so that we can reference it easily. Finally we insert two attributes into it.

Example XML

```
<root>
<Node disablePersistence="true">
    <Name>Mapper</Name>
    <Action>
        <Class-Name>com.test.component.Mapper</Class-Name>
        <Param name="output_url" value="constant:file:///output.xml"/>
        <Param name="xml_url" value="constant:file:///input.xml"/>
        <Param name="xsl_url" value="constant:file:///template.xsl"/>
    </Action>
    <Next-Node>ComposeMessage</Next-Node>
</Node>
<Node disablePersistence="true">
    <Name>DoNotTouchMe</Name>
    <Action>
        <Class-Name>com.test.component.Mapper</Class-Name>
        <Param name="output_url" value="constant:file:///output.xml"/>
        <Param name="xml_url" value="constant:file:///input.xml"/>
        <Param name="xsl_url" value="constant:file:///template.xsl"/>
    </Action>
    <Next-Node>ComposeMessage</Next-Node>
</Node>
</root>
```

Result

```
<root>
<Node disablePersistence="true">
    <Name>Mapper</Name>
    <Action>
        <Class-Name>com.test.component.Mapper</Class-Name>
        <Param name="output_url" value="constant:file:///output.xml"/>
        <Param name="xml_url" value="constant:file:///input.xml"/>
        <Param name="xsl_url" value="constant:file:///template.xsl"/>
        <Param name="new_parameter" constant:true=""/>
    </Action>
    <Next-Node>ComposeMessage</Next-Node>
</Node>
<Node disablePersistence="true">
    <Name>DoNotTouchMe</Name>
    <Action>
        <Class-Name>com.test.component.Mapper</Class-Name>
        <Param name="output_url" value="constant:file:///output.xml"/>
        <Param name="xml_url" value="constant:file:///input.xml"/>
        <Param name="xsl_url" value="constant:file:///template.xsl"/>
    </Action>
    <Next-Node>ComposeMessage</Next-Node>
</Node>
</root>
```